# where to put the excel file to use it in Laravel Excel 3

Tags: laravel, laravel-excel

I would like to use one excel file with Laravel excel and i'm wondering what's the best location to put this file ?

Answer (score 1):

To use the default syntax `Excel::import(new UsersImport, 'users.xlsx');`
put it in `storage/app`